# Change droppable div text based on which draggable item is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

Fellow programmers,
I have 2 draggable div's with unique id's. I need to change the text on a droppable div to a specific text based on which draggable is dropped.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="drag1" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Great</p>
</div>


<div id="drag2" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Poor</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>You Chose</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$( "#drag1, #drag2" ).draggable();

    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui )
    {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html(ui.draggable[0].id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code snippet and it seems to work that way.
I've added data-info attribute as an option to pass some text to the droppable div.

```js
$( "#drag1, #drag2" ).draggable();

$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("p")
            .html($('#'+ui.draggable[0].id).data('info'));
    }
});
```

```css
.ui-widget-content {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<div id="drag1" data-info="My great div was chosen" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Great</p>
</div>


<div id="drag2" data-info="My poor div was chosen" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Poor</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>You Chose</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to say something like "Hey great you chose drag1!" or "You decided to go with drag2!"

Answer (score 0):

Change the ids of your draggable elements to "drag_great" and "drag_poor", instead of "drag1" and "drag2" to match what you have in the jQuery code.

Comment: Sorry, I change my id's while uploading and forgot to switch them.

Comment: And it's still broken? Can you explain what exactly is happening wrong. I made a jsfiddle for the scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/yoxsqosa/. It seems to be working as you wanted.

Comment: I want to be able to add specific text instead of the id.